# java- update table status when an exception is catched

Tags: java, mysql

I've been thinking for a long time and couldn't figure a way to tackle this issue.

I have a Java program that reads a table from MySQL that has Active status. The table looks something like this:

```
UniqueID   FilePath                 Status     
 1          C:\Folder1\abc.pdf       Active
 2          C:\Folder1\def.pdf       Active
 3          C:\Folder1\efg.pdf       Error
```

Idea is straightforward: I locate the file location from filepath, call some function to extract the files and perform indexing processing to it. During the entire process, the status will change from Active to Processing and then to Complete when the programs completes.

Below is the code:

```
 public void doScan_DB() throws Exception {

        try {


            Statement statement = con.connect().createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from filequeue where Status='Active'");

            while (rs.next()) {
                // get the filepath of the PDF document
                String path1 = rs.getString(2);
                int getNum= rs.getInt(1);
                // while running the process, update status : Processing
                updateProcess_DB(getNum);

               // call the index function
                Indexing conn = new Indexing();
                conn.extractDocuments(path1);
                // After completing the process, update status: Complete
               updateComplete_DB(getNum);

             // if error occurs 
// call this method updateError_DB(getNum);


                }


        }catch(SQLException|IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }



    }
```

ExtractDocument method:

```
public void extractDocuments(String path) throws Exception{



        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(path))) {

            if (!document.isEncrypted()) {

                PDFTextStripper tStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                String pdfFileInText = tStripper.getText(document);
                String lines[] = pdfFileInText.split("\\r?\\n");
                for (String line : lines) {
                    String[] words = line.split(" ");
                    // words.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));


                    for (String word : words) {
                        // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
                        // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
                        // uniqueWords.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
                        list.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
                        // uniqueWords.add(word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", ""));
                    }

                }


            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception while trying to read pdf document - " + e);

        }

        String[] words1 =list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        // String[] words2 =uniqueWords.toArray(new String[uniqueWords.size()]);

        // MysqlAccessIndex connection = new MysqlAccessIndex();



        index(words1,path);


        System.out.println("Completed");



    }

}
```

The problem is let's say abc.pdf does not exist so it will throw a file exception error. And I am passing argument to update each row for processing like below:

```
 public void updateProcess_DB(int argument){

  try{



        Statement test = con.connect().createStatement();
     test.executeUpdate("update filequeue SET STATUS ='Processing' where UniqueID= "+argument);

  }catch(Exception e){

      e.printStackTrace();

  }

    }
```

I have another method for updating error status to the table and another for completing the process.

Is there a way to update the status to Error for abc.pdf and status to Complete for def.pdf ?

As so far, my code will throw an exception for the file but still updates both status to Complete. The proper idea is to update only the STATUS that has FileException error thrown in `extractDocuments() method`. Since it catches the exception, it will still always run `updateComplete_DB` in `doScan_DB`.

Is there a proper way to handle this as any suggestion is appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this but I would remove the try/catch from inside extractDocuments and have it around the call to the same method in in doScan_DB

```
try {
     conn.extractDocuments(path1);
     updateComplete_DB(getNum);
} catch (Exception e) {
    updateError_DB(getNum);
}
```

Maybe you should also change into having one method for updating the status

```
public void updateStatus_DB(int id, String status){
   try{
        Statement test = con.connect().createStatement();
        test.executeUpdate("update filequeue SET STATUS ='" + status + "' where UniqueID= "+ id);
   } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: `extractDocuments` isn't throwing exception up and hence, this code will fail. You need to throw exception( prefer not to catch at first place). Also, consuming exceptions with ` e.printStackTrace();` is a very bad idea.

Comment: @SukhpalSingh As I wrote in the text the try/catch should be removed so this code will not fail, read before you type. Yes the error handling is bad but I was only copying existing code to suggest an improvement to make the method reusable, error handling wasn't the main point here.

Comment: Then *would remove the try/catch from inside extractDocuments* must be *must remove the try/catch from inside extractDocuments*

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for your suggestion, I'm gonna give it a try tomorrow

Comment: @SukhpalSingh _would_ refers to the first part of the sentence _"There are several ways to handle this..."_. Give it a break and try to add some constructive response instead of incorrectly trying to mark words.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson As for having one method to update the status, I  wouldn't do that because when the file is being called or processed, I have an UpdateProcess method to change it's status from Active to Processing and once the index is completed, another method to change the status from Processing to Complete.  So I couldn't really see how UpdateStatus_DB would solve this

Comment: @Daredevil It was mostly a suggestion to replace what I guessed is mostly duplicate code since any method changing the status field looks almost the same

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I see. So what happens if I now catch an exception, say FileNotFound exception which was initially caught in ExtractDocument method. Since it's catch inside doScan_DB, I would assume it would update the status to the way I want?

Comment: Yes, it will since the updateComplete_DB method will be called if there is no exception and updateError_DB will be called if extractDocuments throws an exception

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Oh and if there is an exception thrown inside index(words1,path); , will it also be handled in that catch block in do_ScanDB?

Comment: @Daredevil, yes if there is no try/catch in index()

Comment: Oops sorry i just saw your msg. Can we do this in chat?

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake on my side

Comment: Regarding my extractDocument method, is there a way to insert to db directly without storing in an arraylist?